# [AutodeskForge]I would like to know why the conversion fails ifc files contain single quotes at the end of certain attributes

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I would like to know why the conversion fails if certain attributes contain trailing single quotes.

An ifc-file that contains single quotes (') at the end of certain attributes fails to translate.

The API I used

```
POST /modelderivative/v2/designdata/job
```

Target attribute value

```
EL-G35211AN/6-SP/L''
```

Data for the line containing the target attribute value in the ifc-file

```
#2340 = IFCFLOWTERMINAL('32hCanqHP0QAQmHARnRsKT', #2341, '\X2\30107167660E56685177FF0830E630FC30B630FC90E86750FF093011FF7CFF7DFF83FF9159294E95FF086D45578BFF09\X0\ EL-G35211AN/6-SP/L'', '\X2\6A5F566830FB56685177\X0\. \X2\30E630FC30B630FC90E86750\X0\', $, #2353, #2339, $);
```

```
#2346 = IFCLIGHTFIXTURETYPE('2A0TvRw8rCk8EKh4gObqVr', #2341, '\X2\30107167660E56685177FF0830E630FC30B630FC90E86750FF093011FF7CFF7DFF83FF9159294E95FF086D45578BFF09\X0\ EL-G35211AN/6-SP/L'', '\X2\6A5F566830FB56685177\X0\. \X2\30E630FC30B630FC90E86750\X0\', $, $, $, $, $, .NOTDEFINED.);#2390 = IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE('\X2\540D79F0\X0\', '', IFCTEXT('\X2\FF7CFF7DFF83FF9159294E95FF086D45578BFF09\X0\ EL-G35211AN/6-SP/L''), $);
```

```
#2378 = IFCPROPERTYLISTVALUE('table_data', '', (IFCTEXT('SPVER,10,\X2\4ED569D866F830D030FC30B830E730F330B330FC30C9\X0\,'), IFCTEXT('CGRYCODE,403000000000000000,\X2\6A5F56685206985E30B330FC30C9\X0\,,'), IFCTEXT('NAME2,\X2\FF7CFF7DFF83FF9159294E95FF086D45578BFF09\X0\,\X2\578B5F0F540D79F0\X0\,'), IFCTEXT('NAME1,EL-G35211AN/6-SP/L'',\X2\30E130FC30AB30FC578B756A\X0\,')), $);
```

```
#2390 = IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE('\X2\540D79F0\X0\', '', IFCTEXT('\X2\FF7CFF7DFF83FF9159294E95FF086D45578BFF09\X0\ EL-G35211AN/6-SP/L''), $);
#2398 = IFCPROPERTYSINGLEVALUE('\X2\578B756A\X0\', '', IFCTEXT('EL-G35211AN/6-SP/L''), $);
```

manifest

```
{
    "urn": "XXXXXXXXXX",
    "derivatives": [
        {
            "hasThumbnail": "false",
            "name": "XXXXXXXX.ifc",
            "progress": "complete",
            "messages": [
                {
                    "type": "error",
                    "code": "Navisworks-Internal",
                    "message": "Error code: 2 - bec9343c395241f266d3b7af86dee70e041d7687d3b4f0f0c0952b04ff3c39eb.ifc could not be opened because the contents are corrupt or it is currently unavailable.\n\nIt is recommended to re-open your model to avoid data loss.\n"
                },
                {
                    "type": "error",
                    "message": "Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741829",
                    "code": "TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"
                }
            ],
            "outputType": "svf2",
            "status": "failed"
        }
    ],
    "hasThumbnail": "false",
    "progress": "complete",
    "type": "manifest",
    "region": "US",
    "version": "1.0",
    "status": "failed"
}
```

I would like to know what is causing the inability to translate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not closely familiar with the IFC format but the following line from your question seems off:

```
#2340 = IFCFLOWTERMINAL('32...KT', #2341, '\X2\30...09\X0\ EL-G35211AN/6-SP/L'', '\X2\6A...50\X0\', $, #2353, #2339, $);
```

Since the format apparently uses single quotes to delimit string values, the two single quotes seem incorrect. Shouldn't the first quote be escaped?

Also, are you able to open this IFC file in any desktop IFC viewer? If you can, then I'd suggest that you send the IFC file to us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com` (confidentially - we would not share the file with anyone outside of Autodesk), and we would ask our engineering to debug the conversion.